# Running specific commands in monkey not working

Tags: android, monkey

I read this page 
http://hariniachala.blogspot.com/2011/09/android-application-ui-testing-with.html

and when I executed this code

```
./adb -d shell monkey -p package_name --port 1080 &
./adb -d forward tcp:1080 tcp:1080
telnet localhost 1080
```

I faced the following problem

```
C:\Users\subhi\Desktop>adb -d shell monkey -p package_name --port 1080
error: device not found
```

what is the simplest method to do that ?

Comment: Are you testing on a phone or emulator?

Comment: yes of course it is listed

Answer (score 0):

probably the reason why ADB is not finding a device is that you are forcing the search for a physical one (-d option). If you want to interact with an emulated device you should use -e or even no option (ADB should resolve it automatically).
Summing up, if I understood your problem, my suggestion is to launch an AVD, wait until boot and use:

```
adb shell monkey -p <app.package.name> --port <X> &
adb forward tcp:<X> tcp:<X>
telnet localhost <X>
```

where

```
<X>
```

is the port number you want to use.